# Accessing custom contacts using EWS managed API

Tags: c#, ews-managed-api

I've been tasked to create an application (using C# and EWS Managed API) that synchronizes an Outlook contact folder with a Lotus Notes Contacts Database (accessed via SOAP).

So far I've successfully fetched all contacts from Notes and added them to a Public folder on Exchange. But now those contacts should also be available on a smartphone (primarily iPhone), and as far as I know, it is not possible to view contacts in a Public folder from a smartphone?

So this is where I need some help. I've thought about programatically create a local contacts folder and asynchronously delete and re-create the contacts every time a user opens his/her Outlook, but I'm not quite sure that's the best way to go? Also thought about giving a HTML5 app a go, but I have no experience in that area whatsoever, and it also need to be able to work in offline mode as well.

I would really appreciate it if any of you guys have an idea that can lead me in the right direction?